# I am trying to run a specific code on VBA and seeing the following error runtime error run time error-2147319765(8002802b)

Tags: vba, excel, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run a code on excel VBA and trying to select a sheet during the macro run.

```
Sub Selstart()
Dim driver As ChromeDriver
Set driver = New ChromeDriver
driver.Get ("abc.com")
Dim a, b As String
a = "getlam"
b = "strak"
driver.FindElementByXPath(".//*[@id='loginForm']/div[1]/div[1]/input").SendKeys a
driver.FindElementByXPath(".//*[@id='loginForm']/div[1]/div[2]/input").SendKeys b
driver.FindElementByXPath(".//*[@id='Submit_button']").Click
Dim url0 As String
url0 = Sheets("Hyperlinks").Range("F5").Value
driver.Get url0
'open chrome and select page'

Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
SendKeys "^{a}"
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
SendKeys "^{c}"
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
Sheets("dump").Select
Sheets("dump").UsedRange.ClearContents
'clear range contents'

Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
'paste the content'

driver.Get url0
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
driver.FindElementByXPath(".//a[normalize-space()='Next']").Click
'Click on Next button'
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
SendKeys "^{a}"
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
SendKeys "^{c}"
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
Sheets("dump").Select
Range("A130").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

driver.Get url0
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
driver.FindElementByXPath(".//a[normalize-space()='Next']").Click
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
driver.FindElementByXPath(".//a[normalize-space()='Next']").Click
'Click on Next button*2'

Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
SendKeys "^{a}"
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
SendKeys "^{c}"
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
Sheets("dump").Select
Range("A260").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste`
```

The code runs perfectly once in a while but it throws up an error when running "Sheets("dump").Select" . attaching error screenshot

#### Error screenshot

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Can you try ThisWorbook.Sheets("dump").Activate

Comment: I did that it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to avoid using [`.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).  Try the code below:

```
Sub Selstart()
Dim driver As ChromeDriver
Set driver = New ChromeDriver

Dim dumpWS As Worksheet
Dim linkWS As Worksheet

Set dumpWS = Worksheets("dump")
Set linkWS = Worksheets("Hyperlinks")


driver.Get ("abc.com")
Dim a, b As String
a = "getlam"
b = "strak"
driver.FindElementByXPath(".//*[@id='loginForm']/div[1]/div[1]/input").SendKeys a
driver.FindElementByXPath(".//*[@id='loginForm']/div[1]/div[2]/input").SendKeys b
driver.FindElementByXPath(".//*[@id='Submit_button']").Click
Dim url0 As String
url0 = linkWS.Range("F5").Value
driver.Get url0
'open chrome and select page'

Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
SendKeys "^{a}"
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
SendKeys "^{c}"
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
dumpWS.UsedRange.ClearContents
'clear range contents'

dumpWS.Range("A1").Paste
'paste the content'

driver.Get url0
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
driver.FindElementByXPath(".//a[normalize-space()='Next']").Click
'Click on Next button'
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
SendKeys "^{a}"
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
SendKeys "^{c}"
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
dumpWS.Range("A130").Paste

driver.Get url0
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
driver.FindElementByXPath(".//a[normalize-space()='Next']").Click
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
driver.FindElementByXPath(".//a[normalize-space()='Next']").Click
'Click on Next button*2'

Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
SendKeys "^{a}"
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
SendKeys "^{c}"
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
dumpWS.Range("A260").Paste

End Sub
```

Although, I don't think the `.Select` line is throwing the error.  When you hit "Debug", are you sure that's the line that's highlighted? I'm thinking `Element not Found` is an issue with one of the XPaths...